# Solving recurrence equations with 2 base cases

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion

I'm a little confused regarding solving recurrence equations with 2 base cases, so for T(n) =

\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if 0 < $n$ ≤ 2 } \\
T(n - 2) + 3, & \text{if $n$ > 2}
\end{cases}

Using substitution I have T(n) = T(n - 2i) + 3i, and I'm stuck on what to do next, as there are 2 base cases T(2) and T(1).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What if you write out the first few $T$ results and look for a pattern?

Comment: From your substitution result $T(n-2i)+3i$, you want to choose an integer $i$ such that $T(n-2i)$ is a base case, i.e. solve $i$ such that $0 < n-2i \le 2$.

Comment: I thought about trying 1 or 2 = n-2i, but in other questions I see with 1 base case the solution would be n-i = 0, allowing for an easy substitution of T(0), but I am slightly confused on how to do this here

Comment: The inequality $0 < n-2i \le 2$ becomes $\frac n2-1 \le i < \frac n2$, and $i$ has to be an integer. Using ceiling $\lceil\cdot \rceil$ or floor $\lfloor \cdot\rfloor$ functions you may represent that unique $i$ in terms of $n$.

Answer (score 0):

The recursion trees arising from the two base cases are completely independent of each other. Thus we may write for odd $n$
$$T(n)=\frac{3(n+1)}2-2$$
and for even $n$
$$T(n)=\frac{3n}2-2$$
which can be combined as
$$T(n)=3\left\lceil\frac n2\right\rceil-2$$

Comment: How did you result in the first 2 equations?

Comment: @lobsterj Easily provable by induction.